# How to get process builder output text log in real time

Tags: java, process, stream, console, processbuilder

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` to execute a console application that takes one hour to execute.

I want to see output from the console in real time. In my code, the result only appears when the console application is finished.

Here is my code :

```
List<String> cmd;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(cmd);
Process process = pb.start();
process.getOutputStream().close();

InputStream processStdOutput = process.getInputStream();
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(processStdOutput);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // the output is here
}

int w = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: If you just run the windows application from the console does the console show the responsive output you are looking for?

Comment: Finaly i found it pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

Comment: Write an answer to your own question.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. The answer `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT` is not found anywhere in the Duplicate Questions.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by Hoang, just adding:
    `pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);`
would do what you need.  You can include the stderr by adding 
    `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);`